# How to lengthen the time when I'm separated from my car seat when braking?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Often when I brake (hard) in my car, I get lurched forward for a brief moment, then my body would go back to my seat.

I think it's a strange feeling and I found it interesting that this time of separation wasn't always constant. Does this mean that, if I play with enough parameters, I can lengthen it arbitrarily to any amount of time I want?

If I understand the process correctly I'm thinking that if I'm braking over a very long distance, my body would remain separated from the seat for this length of braking (in addition to maybe the time it takes the car suspension system to dampen as well).

Is my understanding correct? Are there other parameters at play as well?

**Edit**:
All answers seem to be concerned about me driving too fast or not wearing my seatbelt. I promise I won't do either of these things.

Comment: Ehh.. loosen the seat belt, **but don't do this as it is unsafe**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the forces look like during a brake condition:

[image: free body diagram]

Please note that I have simplified it a lot. I am not assuming a seat belt **(please wear a seat belt while driving)**. I am assuming that braking results in a horizontal force on the driver (this is a very simplified case).

Typically car seats are inclined backward. That's why you gently press against the seat. If the seat angle is A and your weight is mg (m being your mass, g being acceleration due to gravity), there is a force component **mg*sin(A)** that causes you to gently press against the seat.

When you brake, your car decelerates. Car seat is fixed but you can freely move forward. If braking is creating a deceleration a, then your body will experience a force **ma** in horizontal direction as shown.

If we break this force into two components - one along the seat and one perpendicular to it, the forces look like the image above.

For you to get separated, **ma*cos(A)** needs to balance out **mg*sin(A)**.

In layman terms, it boils down to how hard you are applying the brakes. Now when you apply the brakes, the car will slow down and come to a halt. So if you want to sustain this separation for long, you need to be driving at high speed and then brake just enough that you get separated from the seat and maintain it like that till your car comes to a halt.

**Note: Please don't overspeed or cause yourself any harm trying to do this.**

Answer (score 1):

When the car is moving, both the car seat and your body travels at the same speed. You lurch forward because your car seat slows down faster than your body does. This isn't surprising, since the car slows down first, and your car seat is attached to the car but your body isn't. Your body keeps going until your seat belt pulls you back and changes your original velocity to the new one.

You could lengthen the time when you're separated from the car seat by braking harder. This creates the largest instantaneous discrepancy between your velocity and the car's velocity.

If you want to be separated indefinitely, it's conceptually easy. If you go to outer space such that there's no contact between you and the car, then whether the car slows down or not does not affect your motion, and you just keep going (until you crash into the windshield).

Answer (score 1):

If you are ACTUALLY separated from your seat you are driving tooooo fast or braking too hard. You should feel a lessening of the pressure.

The answer saying you need to brake harder will not increase the time. If you reach the limiting acceleration to 'lift' you then the time is given by the equation of motion v = u + at

Since v = 0 (you stop)
and a is defined by the necessary force to lift you (geometry)

then you can only increase t by starting from a higher value of u (initial velocity)

The roads and your car are NOT a physics laboratory - please drive with consideration for other's safety.